How to prevent client IPs from connecting to each other
can I prevent clients from connecting to each other?
only the client and server are connected
I use the PPPOE client
so only the client to the server is connected
Between PPPOE clients, access is blocked
I use mikrotik
hopefully someone can help
Thank you very much

On a Mikrotik, if you give them a static IP address, you can create a firewall rule that blocks anything but traffic going to one or more addresses, so yes, with a Mikrotik, definitely possible. The question really is, how restrictive do you want this to be? You might be better off blocking ports rather than ip addresses. That way, they can't edit their IP addresses to circumvent it even though it is hard to figure out how you block their access.

What kind of clients – Ethernet, wifi, VPN? This is a very "it depends" question.

ethernet client
